# Change object reference in execution time

Tags: reactjs

I want to modify a command line at run time with React. It is possible ?

Example:
In the statement below I need to modify the customer to another object to be defined at runtime:

blocks.customers.dataIndex = this.state.blocks.customers.dataIndex-1;

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using rest `...` operator e.g

**Examples**

```
//In your case 
blocks.customers.dataIndex = {...this.state.blocks.customers.dataIndex-1};

//for arrays:
      const data = [{name:"max", age:30}] // assign this array into new array with additional object
      var abs =[...data,{name:"gyle",age:20}]; // rest operator create new copy of data array in abs and add new object

//for Objects:
      const data = {name:"max", age:30} //assign this array into new array with additional object
      var abs ={...data}; // rest operator create new copy of object in abs
```

Comment: Improving my question ...

With command Object.keys(this.state.blocks.customers.records[0]) i get the name of the columns of an query i made on the server. I would like with this associated with the MAP command I could avoid having to repeat the refs for each column as below. It is possible ?

`        this.refs.cd_customer.value = this.state.blocks.customers.records[index].cd_customer;
        this.refs.nm_customer.value = this.state.blocks.customers.records[index].nm_customer;
        this.refs.dt_cliente_since.value = this.state.blocks.customers.records[index].dt_cliente_since;`

Comment: you do not want to use this.reffs on each line right ?